# Wii U disc drive spitting out disk after making noises

Tags: technical-issues, wii-u, hardware

My Wii U is behaving like the one in this video:

I have no idea why it's behaving that way, I have kept my Wii U in great condition since I bought it 2 years ago, and I have never had any problems with previous consoles. I have never dropped my Wii U and I always handle with care, which is my I'm really confused and I'm freaking out as to how it broke.

Any disk that I put in (Wii U or Wii), will be spit out from the Wii U (as seen in the video). However, my Wii U still works: the Wii U I bought came with Super Mario 3D World downloaded onto it, and I can play that game perfectly fine, so I have reason to believe it has something to do with disk drive in. My warranty expired (because it's been 2 years), and I wouldn't like to spend $120 to fix it, I'd like to find some cheaper alternative. Is it possible to fix it by opening it up? If so, what should I be looking for Also, if this isn't the place to ask this, what's a better site I can ask this question?

UPDATE: This is what I have tried. I tried a "cleaning disk", but my Wii U just spit out the disk like in the video. I opened up the disk drive and I didn't see anything abnormal (no dust in the disk drive, no small items lodged in), and I noticed whenever I put in any disk that the disk doesn't spin, again I have no idea why this happens. Right now I'm trying the reformatting method, and if that fails well the only thing to do is buy a new disk drive.

UPDATE 2: None of the proposed solutions worked, so I guess I'm going to replace the disk drive.

Comment: You've mentioned that your warranty expired, but it's always worth following this up with Nintendo - just in case. I had a disk drive problem with my Wii some years ago; they sent a freepost sticker, and I sent it away. A week later it was back, good as new, and I never got a bill. Worth checking the official route, even if just to make sure it'll cost you.

Comment: What do you mean by a freepost sticker? The only reason I said it would cost me $120 is because I contacted nintendo support about this and the guy on the phone told me it would be $100 to fix it plus $20 shipping and handling.

Comment: A postage label I printed out and attached to the parcel, meaning I didn't pay for shipping. It probably depends on a lot of factors - this was at least 3 years ago, and in the UK, so things may be different or may have changed over time. If you've already been in touch with Customer Support, then there probably isn't much to be done about the price.

Comment: @RubberDucky - Please don't pressure users to award bounties. They are already notified many times about their bounty expiry, and can choose to award it or not, that is their perogative. Plus a lot of users will wait until the last moment to award bounties as this gives the question and it's answers more time in the spotlight.

Answer (score 6):

Before you go and open up the Wii U or send it in for repairs, it might be worth trying a cleaning CD, as described [here](http://www.nintendonerds.com/categories/wii-u/a-cd-can-be-used-as-a-wii-u-cleaning-disc-r717).

Based on the information given there, it looks like *any* CD-R will work as a cleaning disc. The Wii U will then clean out its disc drive, so if the problem here is a dirty disc drive, this *should* fix it.

If that fails to fix your issue, it might be worth opening up your Wii U and replacing the disc drive (assuming you are comfortable doing this, as I've botched some hardware operations in the past, myself). You can get a replacement disc drive from sites like Amazon (I found a listing for less than $30).

However, this also may not work.

Unfortunately, your best bet to get your Wii U fixed is to send it into Nintendo for repairs. I realize this is less than desirable, as you're no longer covered under warranty.

---

My personal recommendation would be *definitely* try out a cleaning disc, just to make sure the fix isn't super simple, then send it in for repairs if that doesn't work. I'm a bit wary on self-service, because according to [Nintendo support](https://www.nintendo.com/consumer/orders.jsp), if you try to fix your Wii U yourself and are unsuccessful, they ***will not repair it for you***.

> Q: I opened my system to try to repair it myself, but was unsuccessful. Can Nintendo still repair it for me?
>
> A: No. Any system that is found to have been tampered with, modified, otherwise altered, or counterfeit is permanently damaged and cannot be brought back to its original working condition.

Thus, unless you're **really sure** that you will be able to fix it yourself, I wouldn't risk it.

Comment: Well I'm never going to spend 100+ bucks to fix my system, I might as well buy a new one, so I will try what you said and comment what the results are. You say any CD-R, this means any music CD essentially?

Comment: @VishwaIyer according to the post I linked, yeah, it looks like it. Although, even if the system doesn't recognize it as a cleaning CD, it won't harm your Wii U.

Comment: Alright good to know

Comment: @VishwaIyer any luck with the cleaning CD?

Comment: I'm gonna try in a couple of hours. I'm at work right now.

Comment: Well the cleaning CD did the same thing the regular Wii U CDs did: went in and then went out.

Comment: @Vemonus read my update please

Comment: @VishwaIyer sorry, man, I'm not really sure what else you can do. At this point, I'd just send it into Nintendo for repairs or get a new console. :/

Answer (score 1):

As Vemonus said in his answer, the best way would probably be to go for a cleaning CD and to contact Nintendo in the worst case. Do **not** try to repair it yourself by opening it. I have read enough threads with people talking about how they tried to repair it and didn't succeed (or managed to make it worse).

Additionally to those propositions, there is another kinda extreme solution that seems to have worked for some: formatting the system memory of your Wii U. The idea is that you format your Wii U so that the system nearly gets back to the same state it was when you bought your console.

For this option, [this tutorial](http://en-americas-support.nintendo.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/1723/~/how-to-delete-all-content-%26-settings-(format)) would help you. Basically, you have to go in the Wii U "System Settings" menu, and then select "Delete All Content & Settings". After going through the system setup, it seems like the disk ended up staying in for some users, fixing the issue.

Do note though that you should go for this solution only if the cleaning disk option didn't work and if Nintendo has not been able to do anything for you. Do also note that you will [lose your data](http://en-americas-support.nintendo.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/1466/~/what-is-lost-after-formatting-the-system-memory%3F) by using this solution. Yet, if none of the other solutions seemed to have worked, this can still be a potential option to fix your Wii U and make the disc drive working again.

Another possibility might be that something else than dust or such is stuck in your disk drive. I read some topics about people ended up making it work after finding out there was a little leaf in the front of the disk drive, while others found a penny in it because of a kid who put it in there. While I do not think you stuck a penny in your disk drive, it might have happened than a piece of paper accidentally ended up there. Maybe you can then try to check if you can see something in your disk drive opening, and try to carefully remove it from there.

Comment: How would reformatting the system memory fix an issue with the disk drive, feels like a hardware problem for me, not a software problem.

Comment: @VishwaIyer That's what I ended up finding on some threads about the matter, and it solved the problem for some people apparently. We are trying to gather as many solutions as possible there to solve the problem, so I'd rather not put a possible option on the side. Sometimes problems that seem coming from the hardware in the first place can come from the software itself. Just trying to help you there. If it ends up being the only solution to solve your problem, I would have been happy to have put the option there.

Comment: I didn't mean to be rude, I was just asking. I will still try it, as a last resort.

Comment: @Vishwalyer Do not worry, I didn't say you were rude or anything! Sorry if I sounded like it was the case. I seriously hope for you that Vemonus' solutions will be able to solve your problem and that you won't need to go through something that annoying.

Comment: Also just as a question: I had Super Mario 3D World come with my Wii U as a bundle, meaning I don't have a disk for it and it came with the Wii U. If I "Delete All Content & Settings", will I still have the game or will it be gone forever. Also, I'm copying all of my data from the Wii U to a flash drive, but if I "Delete All Content & Settings", I won't be able to copy this data to the Wii U (according to the site)?

Comment: @VishwaIyer [The answer](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/296384/136461) to the question you asked about this exact matter is what I would have answered on that point.

Comment: read my update please

Comment: @VishwaIyer Arg. I'm really sorry than none of the answers worked there. I don't remember finding any other ideas, so I guess the best would be to contact Nintendo now. I am sorry for this.

Answer (score -1):

I found a similar issue here: http://www.neogaf.com/forum/showthread.php?t=910163

Basically, you have to get it replaced.

-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-

BUT>>> Nothing is unfixable!

Ifixit has your back: https://www.ifixit.com/Guide/Nintendo+Wii+U+DVD+Drive+Replacement/12811

^basically tells you how to take it apart and replace the dvd drive^

Comment: When I remove the DVD Drive, can I open it up to see what's wrong with my Wii U? I see screws on the top so I believe I can open the top. If I can, what should I be looking for (if you know) in order to fix my Wii U? I'm kinda against replacing the DVD drive because I'm confused as to how it broke in the first place. Most of the problems I've seen involve sticking a toy in the DVD drive, but I can assure you I haven't done that.

Comment: You can probably open it up. If you break it, no problem because it probably had to be replaced. If you can find the problem and fix it, good for you!