# Wii U - backing up save data onto a flash drive, reformatting the Wii U, and then copying the save data back onto the Wii U

Tags: wii-u

Due to some complications, I might have to reformat my Wii U (basically go to Settings and select "Delete All Content & Settings"). Based on what I read online, if I do this, I will lose all of my save data and any pre-downloaded software. I had Super Mario 3D World pre-downloaded as part of a bundle when I originally bought the Wii U, and I understand that I will lose the game. So I have a couple of questions:

1. I backed up all of the save data/software onto a 16 gb flash drive. Once I reformat my Wii U, can I go to data management and just copy the data from the flash drive to the Wii U and keep all of the save data.
2. From my understanding, my NNID will not be deleted when I reformat the Wii U, so in order to redownload my Super Mario 3d World, I just have to create a new user, link my NNID to this user, and redownload the game from the eShop, is this correct?
3. I had a Wii before my Wii U, and did a system transfer, and right now I have 2 games on my Wii U that I bought from the eShop (Pokemon Rumble and some other game). I didn't see in "Data & Management" an option to copy this data to my flash drive, so when I reformat my Wii U how will I get these 2 games back - do I have to redownload them from the Wii eShop? Also how do I copy the Wii save data for some of my Wii Games (Mario Kart Wii for example) to my flash drive so I can recopy it back.

Just to clarify, I haven't reformatted my Wii U yet, all I have done is copy all of the software/save data I have to a flash drive.

Answer (score 1):

NNID can be transferred to a new user provided it is on the same console.

From [Nintendo](http://en-americas-support.nintendo.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/1670/~/how-to-link-an-existing-nintendo-network-id):

> Once a Nintendo Network ID has been associated to a Wii U console, it can only be moved to a new user on the same console where the account was originally created.

Also from [Nintendo](http://en-americas-support.nintendo.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/1531/~/nintendo-network-id-faq):

> Pre-installed software on the SD card can be re-downloaded from the Nintendo eShop after a system transfer is performed.

Lastly, from [Nintendo](http://en-americas-support.nintendo.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/10748/~/digital-purchases-on-nintendo-systems):

> Most of the games that are available through the Nintendo eShop on Wii U or Nintendo 3DS family systems can also be purchased online through the individual game pages on [www.nintendo.com/games.](http://www.nintendo.com/games) (A Nintendo Account with a linked Nintendo Network ID is required to purchase games through Nintendo's website.) Your game will be automatically downloaded to the system associated to your account

Comment: Well the games I purchased on the Wii Shop channel that are on the Wii Menu of my Wii U (Pokemon Rumble for example), how do I get those games onto a flash drive/sd card, I don't see an option to copy this data to the flash drive. I don't want to rebuy it, I already bought the software. Also, what about the saved data that I have on the flash drive, after I reformat the Wii U, can I use the saved data or not?

Comment: Those questions are answered on the Nintendo page, rather clearly. As I understand it, you can transfer your flash drive contents back to your WiiU after reset and if you use the same NNID on the same console, the eShop titles are simply redownloaded. If you're changing the NNID itself but keeping the system, the Nintendo site says you may need to contact Nintendo and have then assist with the account transfer so that you retain the license if you bought it.